# Why is the footer is standing in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

The footer space stands in the middle of the page at the inside pages and in the mobile and desktop view. Please refer to the inside pages.
site: http://psikologecealbayrak.com

```
    /*  10.0 ===== Footer =====   */

/*   -- "Footer" section (These are the styles for the Footer section) --   */



.site-footer {
    padding: 30px 0 0px;
}

.footer-branding:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.footer-branding {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.site-footer .widget-area {
    clear: both;
    padding: 75px 0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.widget-area .widget {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
.widget-area .inline-social-icons{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: in last second when i was posting your fixed code , your q closed

Comment: try delete your main id and you will recognize that , set your main id to 100% without margin , it will fix your problem and no your q not answered anywhere its just UI problem

Answer (score 1):

You could try positioning the footer on the bottom of the page with absolute position.
Add this to your css

```
body{
   padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.site-footer{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: result: https://pasteboard.co/IMVRABvd.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
footer{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0px ;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
```

Comment: result:
https://ibb.co/HhMT7Gy

Comment: Could you try adding the body {} and footer and see if it works now?

Comment: yes I added but not changed display

Comment: Could you provide the HTML as well.